# Посчитать количество лабораторных занятий в группе

Tags: java

Суть задания такова: создать перечисляемый тип данных, который содержит информацию о виде университетского занятия ( «лекция», «лабораторная работа», «практика»). Создать класс «Учебный предмет», который содержит следующие поля: Название предмета, вид занятия, Название группы. Создать 5 объектов данного класса и поместить их в массив. Вывести Количество лабораторных занять для группы ЛА-71.

Вот мой код:

```
public enum UniversityClasses {
// LECTION - лекция, LAB - лабораторное занятие, PRACTISE - практическое занятие
    LECTION, LAB, PRACTISE
}

public class Subject {
    private String subjectName;
    private UniversityClasses universityClasses;
    private String groupName;

    public Subject(String subjectName, UniversityClasses universityClasses, String groupName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.universityClasses = universityClasses;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public UniversityClasses getUniversityClasses() {
        return universityClasses;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("Subject name: " + subjectName);
        System.out.println("Kind of classes : " + universityClasses);
        System.out.println("Group name : " + groupName);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

public class University {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Subject firstSubject = new Subject("Math", UniversityClasses.LECTION, "LA-71");
        Subject secondSubject = new Subject("Physics", UniversityClasses.LAB, "LA-71");
        Subject thirdSubject = new Subject("Chemistry", UniversityClasses.LAB, "LA-71");
        Subject fouthSubject = new Subject("Programming", UniversityClasses.LECTION, "LA-71");
        Subject fifthSubject = new Subject("Physical culture", UniversityClasses.PRACTISE, "LA-71");


        Subject[] subjects = {firstSubject, secondSubject, thirdSubject, fouthSubject, fifthSubject};

        for (Subject subject : subjects) {
            if (subject.getUniversityClasses() == UniversityClasses.LAB) {
                subject.printInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге в аутпуте у меня выводит такую информацию:

```
Subject name: Physics
Kind of classes : LAB
Group name : LA-71


Subject name: Chemistry
Kind of classes : LAB
Group name : LA-71
```

Но возник вопрос: как количество лабораторных занятий вывести обычным числом?
Буду благодарен всем Вашим ответам и пожеланиям.

Comment: Делайте счетчик, увеличивающийся каждый раз, когда натыкаетесь на `Group name`, равный(`.equals(..)`) "LA-71"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class University {
//переменная для  количество лаб
static int countLab = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Subject firstSubject = new Subject("Math", UniversityClasses.LECTION, "LA-71");
    Subject secondSubject = new Subject("Physics", UniversityClasses.LAB, "LA-71");
    Subject thirdSubject = new Subject("Chemistry", UniversityClasses.LAB, "LA-71");
    Subject fouthSubject = new Subject("Programming", UniversityClasses.LECTION, "LA-71");
    Subject fifthSubject = new Subject("Physical culture", UniversityClasses.PRACTISE, "LA-71");


    Subject[] subjects = {firstSubject, secondSubject, thirdSubject, fouthSubject, fifthSubject};

    for (Subject subject : subjects) {
        if (subject.getUniversityClasses() == UniversityClasses.LAB) {
            //если гетКласс == Класс.ЛАБ то увеличиваем счетчик 
            countLab++;
            subject.printInfo();
        }
    }
    //Вывод счетчика лаб
    System.out.println("Колличество лаб =  " + countLab);
}
```

}

Comment: Cпасибо за помощь!